# Cakephp 1.3 \persistent\ is not writable....\models\ is not writable

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

Im currently trying to spin up a application, but when I run WAMP and try to access my site I get the following errors.....\models\ is not writable .....\persistent\ is not writable.....\app\tmp\cache\ is not writable. Now with that being said I have did my homework and looked around and it seems there is a permissions problem within my application and I need to set permissions with the following....chmod -R 777 app/tmp , but Im not sure how I got about setting those permissions. In addition, my website is basically a white screen with a little text. Can someone set me straight. Your input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok I got some errors to go away by opening app/config/core.php file and commented Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);....which was line 94. Now I only see app\tmp\cache\ is not writable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem. I added 3 folders inside the tmp folder. The first was cache. Afterwards I drilled down into the cache folder and added 2 additional folders (models,persistant). After that was done I was still getting one error (\app\tmp\cache\ is not writable). To fix it I opened Apache and went to httpd.conf file and edited #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so.....I removed the # and that solved my headache!! I hope this posts helps someone!!

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else with the problem:

I had this problem even after doing a `chmod -R 777 app/tmp`

What fixed my problem: `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t 'tmp'`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is needed when SELinux is running in "enforcing" mode.